# Understanding Hadoop program entry point and questions

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

Background:
I am new Hadoop and learning stuffs by going through Youtube videos. I am using Cloudera QuickStart VM for practical purposes. While running WordCount example provided by Cloudera "hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar", I am unable to find the entry point of the program.

Here is the source code link,
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/2.0.0-cdh4.0.0/org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordCount.java?av=f

Questions,
1) What is the entry point of WordCount Program or What is the Flow?

I am sure its not main method of WordCount.java as i get below mentioned error when i use WordCount as program name. 
   [cloudera@localhost hadoop-mapreduce]$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar WordCount /user/cloudera/harsha/input /user/cloudera/harsha/output
Unknown program 'WordCount' chosen.
  {MORE PROGRAMS HERE}
  teravalidate: Checking results of terasort
  wordcount: A map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.

2) How CLASSPATH is being set?

With the following statement, program runs fine. How are we referring the required libraries? 
   [cloudera@localhost hadoop-mapreduce]$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar wordCount /user/cloudera/harsha/input /user/cloudera/harsha/output

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

You can set `CLASSPATH` with this command:

```
javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```